# How can I convert same signatured types accross each other in golang?

Tags: go

I want to convert from;

```
type MyType map[string]interface{}
```

to;

```
logrus.Fields // map[string]interface{}
```

My code is;

```
func newAction(data interface{}) { // data comes as 'MyType'
    df := data.(logrus.Fields)
}
```

I take this error;

```
interface conversion: interface {} is MyType, not logrus.Fields
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question uses a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).  A type assertion asserts that an interface value is a specific type.  It does not convert types.

Use a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to convert between the types:

```
var v1 MyType
var v2 logrus.Fields

v2 = logrus.Fields(v1)
v1 = MyType(v2)
```

If you have a function that can accept either type, use a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) and then convert each specific type:

```
func newAction(data interface{}) {
    var df logrus.Fields
    switch v := data.(type) {
    case logur.Fields:
        df = v
    case MyType:
        df = logrus.Fields(v)
    default:
        // handle error
    }
    ... do something with df
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't guess to make standard conversion for custom types.